# Jersey based API call from CURL

Tags: jersey

I need to use CURL as follows to invoke the API

```
curl http://api.somedomain.com/v1/someresource \

-d param1=3123345 \

-d param2=65098 \

-d description= “description”
```

How should I write the respective method? I tried with QueryParam and PathParam. But didn't worked? Need help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a post method and your parameters are passed as form parameters:

```
@POST
@Path("/someresource")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED})
public void someresource(@FormParam("param1") String param1, ...) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, actually FormParam couldn't be used with GET methods. That's where I was making mistake.

Comment: Is it possible to use FormParam with GET method?